# Is there any way to discover the traffic of a site I don't control?

Tags: traffic

Given the following:

- The website does not call any external images or scripts, all the content is hosted on a server that is in our control.
- The website does not contain the meta tag, nor does it contain the html file that would authorize a Google Account access to Webmaster Tools.
- The access logs have not been provided to any 2nd or 3rd party.

Is it possible for a 3rd party to get an idea of how many hits the site is getting, or are they limited to just seeing how high the site ranks? How could the 3rd party determine how well the site is doing under these restrictions? Is there a website for that that you know of?

Comment: Alexa is my number one go to. To give you a benchmark (you will only get a world rank, not actual page views number) my site is currently number #565,596 globally, and the page views in the past week is 339.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of tools to do this. If the website has any advertising, then you can probably get the statistics using something something like [Google Ad Planner](https://www.google.com/adplanner/), or whatever ad network that they use (they disclose that because people who are looking to buy advertising want to know how many page views they get).

If they website doesn't have any advertising (this is the case in your question), then there are tools that can *estimate* the amount of traffic a website gets. They do this by tracking the webpages that a percentage of internet users visit, and then assume that the rest of the internet visits the same pages. Again, this at best provides a rough estimate of a websites traffic.

Two websites that provide traffic estimates are [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com) and [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com), though there are probably more out there. I would recommend taking data from multiple services, so that way you have less of a chance of getting inaccurate data.

Another tool is [Google Trends](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=wikipedia.org), which gets it's data from the amount of search traffic a website receives. It doesn't show the actual amount of traffic a website receives, but it does show whether there was a change in traffic that the website receives.

You can also guess how much traffic a website receives by using many factors, like what keywords the site ranks high in, or how many comments the site gets (if they have comments), or based on how many visitors similar sites receive. This isn't very accurate, but it may be the only option available to you.

Comment: Something not really related with the question, but more with this answer: Keyword tool of Google Adwords has an estimate of the traffic volume, however is not very accurate (more than trends tho).

Comment: "tracking the webpages that a percentage of internet users visit" -  how might they do this? Are these users that perhaps have a certain toolbar or app installed on their machine?

Comment: @w3d that's how alexa does it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have **any** external scripts, nobody can determine **exactly** how much hits your website has.
However, google, bing and other search websites log the activity to your website. In google  webmastertools/analytics you can make these statistics available for public, so make sure to check that. I don't know if bing also has the possibility to share these statistics.

Another way of determine the amount of visitors is to look at you position in the search engines on specific keywords, check the amount of links to your website (google: link:yourwebsite.com) and calculate how much people will go to your site by clicking the results. It is not very accurate, but can give a global view on the situation.