# How can I find the approximate daily traffic of a site which I don't own?

Tags: traffic, statistics, suggestions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to discover the traffic of a site I don’t control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/is-there-any-way-to-discover-the-traffic-of-a-site-i-dont-control)

I want to find the approximate daily traffic of a site which isn't ours, and the site is located in other country than US (in Greece - hence no Quantcast or Compete.com afaik) and it doesn't use Google Ads (hence no Google Ad Planner).

I know about Alexa but the site(s) has/have relatively low traffic and the Alexa's rank isn't very useful (same stands to Google Trends). Or perhaps I should look more at Alexa's data?

Any other ideas?

PS: I looked before posting [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/is-there-any-way-to-discover-the-traffic-of-a-site-i-dont-control) and [here](http://bloggerspassion.com/check-website-traffic-5-ways-to-determine-traffic-to-a-website/). No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out and say that it isn't really possible, at least, without asking the webmaster of the site.

You can draw estimates from things like Alexa, but they're poor estimates at best.